# Switch job on online Node jenkins

Tags: plugins, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have jenkins and job in jenkins with selection "Node" (Server) by users and "Label Expression" (ex. server1||server2). But, if my server1 is gone to offline, I want to start my job on server2 automatically. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins' node labels are supposed to be used the other way round. See *Manage Jenkins* → *Manage Nodes* → select a node → *Configure* → Click 
[image] to the right of the *Labels* field:

> *Labels (AKA tags) are used for grouping multiple slaves into one logical group.*

So each of your servers (*Server1*, *Server2*) should have the same label assigned to it. Let's say *build.* Define this in *Label Expression* in your project.

Select *Ignore offline nodes* under *This build is parameterized* → *Node* → *Node eligibility.*

Such, if a user selects an offline node the other one of the group should be taken (if this one is online).

Comment: Borser, yes, you are right, but if user have a choice where start job, this job automatically wait when the server will be start.

Comment: @ЮрийМаслов What if you create a label as described in my answer and _Add parameter_ → _Label: build_ to the parameterized build section?

Comment: @GeroldBoser, yes, but it said: "(pending—There are no nodes with the label ‘Job triggered without a valid online node, given where: server1’)"

Comment: @ЮрийМаслов Apparently the _Node_ parameter takes precedence, which is OK. But it ignores the _Label_ afterwards, which is not - in case the selected is down. On the other hand: What's the point of defining a job being able to run on one of two nodes but letting the user decide rather than Jenkins itself on which it should run?